# BeautifulSoup remove p tags with a class

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

there is a novel i am trying to **scrape** and the HTML has a few p tags with a class which is like embedded text (is not visible in browser but shows up on **scraped** text) and i am trying to remove it , the **class name varies** so ***i want to remove the p tags having a class***.
the class name changes in every page(it is a set of radom letters)
this is the part of the HTML

```html
<p>However, those musings dissipated as soon as he exited the school entrance.</p>
<p class="antvol">Visit lightnovelworld[.]com for a better experience</p>
<p>‘What’s going on. What’s going on!’</p>
```

whats expected:

```html
    <p>However, those musings dissipated as soon as he exited the school entrance.</p>
    <p>‘What’s going on. What’s going on!’</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated , Thanks

Comment: soup.find_all('p',class_=True) did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method to remove a tag.

Since the `<p>` tag that you want to remove has a class - `antvol`, first select that `<p>` tag and remove it using `.decompose()`.

Here is how it is done.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<p>However, those musings dissipated as soon as he exited the school entrance.</p>
<p class="antvol">Visit lightnovelworld[.]com for a better experience</p>
<p>‘What’s going on. What’s going on!’</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
p = soup.find('p', class_='antvol')
p.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   However, those musings dissipated as soon as he exited the school entrance.
  </p>
  <p>
   ‘What’s going on. What’s going on!’
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i get this , but  the thing is the class name varies in different pages . is there a way to select a p tag with has a class name ?

Comment: How does it look like ? Could you share the URL and what do you like to scrape ?

Comment: [link]https://www.lightnovelworld.com/novel/everyone-else-is-a-returnee-19072354/chapter-0 [link]